# Getting error saying I must override superclass method, but parent class has that method to override

Tags: java, android

I’m getting a 
“  The methed startActivityForResult(Intent,int) must override a superclass methed” when trying to compile code from facebook sdk.

I asked about this before and got the empression the eeror message was their because their was no super class to override.

I looked through the Facebook sample code to see if it had a  class to override, and it does.
I can just take out the line to make the error go away.

I was wondering if some one could explain why I’m getting this error when it seems like the error does not exits. (I am still learning java never had a course)
Code:

```
interface StartActivityDelegate {
    /* THIS IS THE METHED THAT’S BEING OVERIDE BELOW AND 
     * I GET A ERROR MESSAGE DON’T UNDERSTAND WHY I’M GETTING
     *THE ERROR MESSAGE WHEN THE SUPER METHOD EXISTS */

    public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode);

    public Activity getActivityContext();
}

void setContext(final Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    // We rely on individual requests to tell us how to start an activity.
    startActivityDelegate = null;
}

void setContext(final Activity activity) {
    this.context = activity;

    // If we are used in the context of an activity, we will always use that activity to
    // call startActivityForResult.
    startActivityDelegate = new StartActivityDelegate() {
        /* THIS IS WHERE I GET THE ERRROR MESSAGE
         * “The methed startActivityForResult(Intent,int) must override a
         * superclass methed”*/
        @Override
        public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode) {
            activity.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
        }

        @Override
        public Activity getActivityContext() {
            return activity;
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java 1.5 it was not allowed to use @Override on class methods implementing interface methods. This seems to be your case

Comment: Hi,Thank you so much.  Facebook said I could use version 5.0 or 6.0.  Figured the old version would be better.  I never would have figured this out, thank you :)